Passing only a single ViewModel from a composite ViewModel to an HTTPPost method
I have a composite view model, that contains a model for displaying an information, and a model for reading information from the user, so I can validate it. The problem is that when I try passing only the model for reading information as a parameter, it's values are null. But when I try passing the whole composite view model, I get the correct values. I want to validate only the model for reading information with ModelState.IsValid and I don't need the whole composite view model being passed. Maybe there is some way to specify what model the HTTPPost method should expect to receive?
Here is the composite view model:
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel() { }

    public ProductViewModel(ProductDisplayModel productDisplayModel)
    {
        ProductDisplayModel = productDisplayModel;
        CreateReviewModel = new CreateReviewModel();
    }

    public ProductDisplayModel ProductDisplayModel { get; set; }
    public CreateReviewModel CreateReviewModel { get; set; }
}

The view, I'm trying to get the values from:
@model ProductViewModel
<form class="add-review-container" method="post" asp-action="CreatedReview" asp-controller="Review">
    <input name="productID" value="@Model.ProductDisplayModel.Product.ProductID" hidden />
    <div class="information-container">
        <div class="profile-container">
            <img class="profile-picture"></img>
            <div class="username-container">
                <p class="username">@User.Identity.Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rating-container">
            <div class="rating">
                @for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    <input value="@i" id="star_@i" type="radio" asp-for="CreateReviewModel.Rating">
                    <label title="@i" for="star_@i"></label>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea class="review-input-box" placeholder="Write a review about the product..." asp-for="CreateReviewModel.Comment"></textarea>
    <div class="post-review-button-container">
        <button class="post-review-button">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>

This is the method, where the input values are passed correctly:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatedReview(int productID, ProductViewModel viewModel) //here the values are passed correctly in viewModel.CreateReviewModel
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //code
    }
}

This is the method, where the input values are null:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatedReview(int productID, CreateReviewModel viewModel)//here the values are null
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //code
    }
}


the only thing being POSTed are the fields inside the form.  If you wanted to include both, you'd need a bunch of hidden fields.  As is it's a mashup of values.  Not sure why the one is valid, but maybe include those 2 models.

As you have a composite view model, and you just want to pass only the model for reading information as a parameter. So, you can achieve this functionality using a partial view.
You can modify your view like this:

Create a partial view named _CreatedPartial for example. Then you can move the code that related to the CreateReviewModel to this partial view.

@model CreateReviewModel

<div class="information-container">
    <div class="profile-container">
        <img class="profile-picture"></img>
        <div class="username-container">
            <p class="username">user name like liya</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-container">
        <div class="rating">
            @for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                <input value="@i" id="star_@i" type="radio" name="Rating">
                <label title="@i" for="star_@i"></label>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<textarea class="review-input-box" placeholder="Write a review about the product..." name="Comment"></textarea>


And in your main view named CreatedReview, you should reference this partial view in the original place.

<div>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_CreatedPartial", Model.CreateReviewModel)
</div>

Result:

